# Calling IBAction from void

Tags: ios, uibutton, nstimer

This is my code. I want that the button changes when the timer reaches 0 but it doesn't work:

```
-(void) SwitchView{

    [switchingTimer invalidate];
    self.SwitchingTimer = nil;
    [self bomb:nil];
}

-(IBAction)bomb:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black_bomb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    int xmin = ([button frame].size.width)/2;
    int ymin = ([button frame].size.height)/2;

    int x = xmin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width - button.frame.size.width);
    int y = ymin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height - button.frame.size.height);
    [button setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];


    [self flower:sender];
}

-(IBAction)flower:(UIButton *)sender{

    UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_rose_flower_6.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    int xmin = ([button2 frame].size.width)/2;
    int ymin = ([button2 frame].size.height)/2;
    int x = xmin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width - button2.frame.size.width);
    int y = ymin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height - button2.frame.size.height);
    [button2 setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];
if (self.switchingTimer == nil) {
    self.switchingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(SwitchView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: You should identify the difference of your statements [self bomb:nil];
and [self flower:sender];
then you will be able to understand, if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling
`[self bomb:nil];`
with `nil` for the sender.

but the `bomb` method uses the sender:

```
-(IBAction)bomb:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
```

but the call sends `nil` for `sender`.

Either provide the `UIButton` pointer on the `bomb` call
or do not use `sender` but a `UIButton` pointer.

The `UIButton` pointer can be from an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: I can't understand it...

Comment: Someone could help me?